# Check differences between dict inside lists

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm trying to get the differences from two json files (olddata and actual_products). The problem of the script is the output, it should be "no change" instead i'm getting y["link"].

Example of my jsonfile(olddata, the other one is the same):

```
[{
    "status": "sold_out",
    "link": "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products/omaa076t19e740660110#",
    "ids": "product_26781",
    "title": "\nOFF-WHITE\u2122 X NIKE T-SHIRT\n"
},
{
    "status": "sold_out",
    "link": "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products/omaa076t19e740661001#",
    "ids": "product_26782",
    "title": "\nOFF-WHITE\u2122 X NIKE T-SHIRT\n"
},
{
    "status": "in_stock",
    "link": "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products/omaa076t19e740661910#",
    "ids": "product_26783",
    "title": "\nOFF-WHITE\u2122 X NIKE T-SHIRT\n"
}]
```

Example of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

def load_data(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return(json.load(f))

def save_new_data(data, file):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

class ABC():
    def __init__(self):
        self.old_data = load_data('olddata.json')
        self.actual_products = load_data('newdata.json')

    def checkdiff(self):
        for x in self.old_data:
            for y in self.actual_products:
                if(x['status'] == "sold_out" and y['status'] == "in_stock"):
                    print("The item is available:", y["link"])
                else:
                    print("no change")

def main():
    s = ABC()
    s.checkdiff()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

"i expected as output no change instead i got the item is available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use your code ,change your function `checkdiff` to:

```
def checkdiff(self):
    for i in range(len(self.old_data)):
        if(self.old_data[i]['status'] == "sold_out" and self.actual_products[i]['status'] == "in_stock"):
            print("The item is available:", self.actual_products[i]["link"])
        else:
            print("no change")
```

output:

```
no change
no change
no change
```

Answer (score 1):

`checkdiff` has incorrect logic:

```
for x in self.old_data:
    for y in self.actual_products:
```

will loop over the 9 (x,y) pairs where x is in `old_data` and y in `actual_products`. It will therefore fail when you compare (e.g.) the first item of the first list with the second item of the second list.

What you probably want is

```
for x, y in zip(self.old_data, self.actual_products):
```

which will loop on the 3 (x,y) pairs where the same index in the JSON list is kept.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this much more efficiently using `pandas` and `joining` on similar features.

`pip install pandas` if you don't have it yet.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(old_data)

df.head()

             ids                                               link    status                          title
0  product_26781  https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products...  sold_out  \nOFF-WHITE™ X NIKE T-SHIRT\n
1  product_26782  https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products...  sold_out  \nOFF-WHITE™ X NIKE T-SHIRT\n
2  product_26783  https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products...  in_stock  \nOFF-WHITE™ X NIKE T-SHIRT\n

joined = pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', on='ids', suffixes=('_new', '_old'))

joined.where(joined.status_new != joined.status_old).link_new.dropna()
Series([], Name: link_new, dtype: object)

joined.where(joined.status_new == joined.status_old).link_new.dropna() 
0    https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products...
1    https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products...
2    https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products...
Name: link_new, dtype: object
```